# OpenAM only works if I use the FQDN

Tags: centos, openam

When I do a curl command on the server I'm running openam on it works fine as long as I use the FQDN.

`curl https://<fqdn>:port/openam/XUI/#login/`

However if I call it by IP address:

`curl https://<ipaddress>:port/openam/XUI/#login/`

it returns:

`{"code":400,"reason":"Bad Request","message":"FQDN \"<ipaddress>\" is not valid."}`

I set up the `/etc/hosts` to include a line for `<ipaddress> <fqdn>` but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

OpenAM uses cookies for SSO tokens, and cookies only work with a FQDN. You can not use a IP address

Comment: I'm trying to use openam as a rest service to validate a user/password. Am I going about that wrong?

Comment: My last comment was vague. I am using https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/12.0.0/dev-guide/chap-rest#rest-api-auth example

Comment: Not sure how following an example guide is relevant to how you are accessing your servers. The REST APIs can be only accessed through valid FQDNs. The new AM5 release for example will set cookies as part of /json/authenticate responses.